# Как очистить input после закрытия модального окна?

Tags: javascript, modx

подскажите, как очистить input после закрытия модального окна

инпуты должны очищаться после закрытия модального окна, когда пользователь не отправил заявку

Comment: Без кода вам никто поможет, добавьте к вопрос код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let myInput = document.querySelector('input') 

myInput.value = "";
```